# Sharing Redux Constant Actions Between Server and Client

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm working on a web application that employs React/Redux on the front end, and Node.js/Redux on the back end.

I currently maintain a set of Redux action constants that are identical on both the front and back end, is there any Redux specific way to share these actions to dry up the code and minimize repeated code?

Answer (score 0):

If you store your front-end and back-end as one project you can move your action types to a sharable folder. For example you have an `app` folder with `front-end`, `back-end` and `sharable` folders.